# How to check text and underscore mistakes - Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a text and with the help of API I analyze the text and have words with mistakes. Here is the response. Bad "is" and suggestions are "am" and "will be"

[image]

So the problem is if I change "is" with "am" it changes it in all text. But I need to change only in place where mistake been found. Please give suggestions how to recognize in the text only error words and switch them with the first item of the API response "better" array

Comment: Use the StringBuilder and try to achieve goal for more details please check-https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder

Comment: Please use code snippets and not screenshots if you want people to help!

Answer (score 0):

as per my observation of this JSON response, with each error, you are getting an `offset` and `length` value. Assuming that the `offset` refers to the startIndex of error word (i.e. `is` or engeneer`) and` lenght`refers to the length of the error word. You can make use of`String#replaceRange` function to replace the incorrect word. (Ref: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace-range.html)

So, in your case following can be the code:

```kotlin
val input = "I is software engeneer"

// API call here

var result = input
response.errors
  .sortByDescending { it.offset } // We should start replacing from end to avoid chaning the offset for other errors.
  .forEach { error ->
    result = result.replaceRange(
        error.offset,
        error.ofset + error.length,
        error.better[0] ?: throw RuntimeError("No alternative found")
    )

  println(result)
}
```